# How does one create a shared_ptr to pass to a function that takes a void *

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

That's pretty much it.  I need to allocate memory and pass it to a function that takes a void *.  I'd like to use a shared_ptr but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What does the function do with the argument? Also, I think it would be possible to allocate memory as a char array (e.g with `std::vector<char>`, and pass `&vec[0]` to the functions).

Comment: the function serializes a google::protobuf into the memory.  a header is prepended and the block is sent over the wire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
boost::shared_ptr<int> myInt(new int(5));

call_some_function(myInt.get());
```

This only let's the function use the `int*`. It shouldn't try to delete it or take ownership.

---

If you want just raw memory, use a `vector`:

```
std::vector<char> memory(blockSize);

call_some_function(&blockSize[0]);
```

Again, the memory belongs to the `vector`.

---

If your function *does* want ownership, there's no need to wrap it into something, since you won't be managing it:

```
call_some_function(new int);
call_some_function(new char[blockSize]);
```

Make sure the function will be releasing it with a call to `delete`/`delete[]`. If not (for example, it intends to use `free()`), you'll need to use `malloc` instead:

```
template <typename T>
T* malloc_new(void)
{
    void* memory = std::malloc(sizeof(T));
    if (!memory)
        throw std::bad_alloc();

    try
    {
        return new (memory) T();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::free(memory);
        throw;
    }
}

call_some_function(malloc_new<int>());
call_some_function(malloc(blockSize));
```

Comment: +1, Really good answer. Beware when creating memory at the place of call (when the called function takes ownership) when more than one operation take place: `foo( bar(), new int(5) )` might leak if `new int(5)` is executed before `bar()` and `bar()` throws an exception. It is safer (even if longer) to use smart pointers: `std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int(5)); foo( bar(), p.release() );` not nice, but safe.

Answer (score -3):

you can also use std::string as a reference counted memory blob container. It is as efficient as shared_ptr on char * vector (maybe better)

Comment: `std::string` is most certainly not a reference counted container.

Comment: sure it is - the spec does not require it to be but all actual implementations are - including thread safety on the refernce counts just like shared_ptr

Comment: I don't think VS/Dinkumware is reference counted.

Comment: There is no way for `std::string` and `shared_ptr<char>` to behave identically no matter what optimizations the library chooses to employ, unless you are dealing with immutable data. And that is a pretty small subset of the uses of smart pointers.

Comment: Using std::string for this is terrible advice.